# Is it normal for a package to request [sudo] in order to install a package? (this case pdf-tools) concerned about password integrity

Tags: package-repositories, install, pdf-tools, passwords

I installed pdf-tools through MELPA, and then labels it as installed on a restart but kept viewing pdfs through doc-view. So using `M-x pdf-tools-install` it requested the `sudo` password in order to install :

```
    -*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-20190413.2018/build/server/" -*-
Comint started at Wed Apr 24 22:14:06

/home/xel/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-20190413.2018/build/server/autobuild -i /home/xel/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-20190413.2018/
---------------------------
    Installing packages    
---------------------------
apt-get install autoconf
              automake
              g++
              gcc
              libpng-dev
              libpoppler-dev
              libpoppler-glib-dev
              libpoppler-private-dev
              libz-dev
              make
              pkg-config
[sudo] password for usr1: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
```

and then finalizes with the message:

```
===========================
   Build succeeded. :O)    
===========================

Comint finished at Wed Apr 24 22:16:38
```

1) Is this typical?

2)It was not expected that Emacs would ask for that level of access. Would this have been protected as a direct communication to the terminal?

3) regardless of this, DocView is still the default when opening a pdf file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you were asked for your password was that `apt-get install` was being invoked to install the additional software (`poppler` and friends) needed by `pdf-tools`.

> 1) Is this typical?

No -- the vast majority of elisp packages do not attempt to automatically install other system requirements.  It's not uncommon for other system software to be *required* by an elisp library, but `pdf-tools` is unusual in attempting to streamline the entire process from inside Emacs.

> 2) It was not expected that Emacs would ask for that level of access. Would this have been protected as a direct communication to the terminal?

Emacs itself wasn't asking directly; the install process was running a make command which included that `sudo apt-get install` command (which of course will prompt for a password).  I would *expect* the password entry to have been as secure as it would be in any other such interaction with an external process in Emacs, but I don't have sufficient knowledge to make statements about these mechanisms.

> 3) regardless of this, DocView is still the default when opening a pdf file

That does seems unexpected.  Have you tried restarting Emacs?

Comment: I did restart and nothing changed in having `pdf-tools` work. Is there reason to believe that malicious content is obtained or that some security hole is introduced?

Comment: I wouldn't be alarmed.  Certainly the `apt-get install` packages should be as secure as any other.  You'd need to look at the pdf-tools build scripts to see what it's doing in detail. Did you add `(pdf-tools-install)` to your init file, per the instructions?

Comment: "To complete the installation process, you need to activate the package by putting `(pdf-tools-install)` somewhere in your [init file]. Alternatively, and if you care about start-up time, you may want to use `(pdf-loader-install)`" -- https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools#installing

Comment: thanks for the reassurance. I have `(pdf-tools-install)` and it does not change the loading tool when a pdf is selected to be seen in a buffer. I have looked at the various issues that could be causing the failure and tried solutions by copying other init.el contents with no luck. The security issue is my main concern